# Концепт "вектор или массив"

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, концепты

Пытаюсь придумать концепт для ситуации

```
template<typename T, typename C>
```

где C должен быть либо `vector<T>`, либо `array<T,N>` с произвольным `N`. Естественно, `is_same` не работает. Не подскажете, как это сделать?

Я могу выложить тут свои неработающие попытки, но, по-моему, и без них понятно, что я пробовал и это не просьба сделать домашку :)

**Добавление для user7860670**

Я сделал так:

```
template<typename T, typename C>
class t_IsVectorOrArray
{
    public: static constexpr bool value{false};
};

template<typename T, typename Item, ::std::size_t count>
class t_IsVectorOrArray<T,::std::array<Item, count>>
{
    public: static constexpr bool value{is_same_v<T,Item>};
};

template<typename T, typename Args>
class t_IsVectorOrArray<T,::std::vector<Args>>
{
    public: static constexpr bool value{is_same_v<T,Args>};
};


template<typename T = double, typename C = vector<T>>
requires (t_IsVectorOrArray<T,C>::value)
struct Container
{
    C c;
};
```

Вы это имели в виду?

Кажется, работает, но я был вынужден убрать три точки в шаблоне для вектора. Это критично? Теоретически для аллокатора не по умолчанию будут неприятности?

**Второе добавление для user7860670**

Как говорил пацан из "Ералаша", я понимаю, что они не пересекаются, но почему они не пересекаются?

```
template<typename T, typename C>
class t_IsVectorOrArray
{
    public: static constexpr bool value{false};
};

template<typename T, ::std::size_t count>
class t_IsVectorOrArray<T,::std::array<T, count>>
{
    public: static constexpr bool value{true};     };

template<typename T, typename... Args>
class t_IsVectorOrArray<T,::std::vector<T, Args...>>
{
    public: static constexpr bool value{true};
};

template<typename T = double, typename C = vector<T>>
requires (t_IsVectorOrArray<T,C>::value)
struct Container
{
    C c;
};

int main()
{
    Container<int,vector<int>> c1;
    Container<int,vector<double>> c2;
    Container<int,array<double,5>> c3;
    Container<int,array<int,4>> c4;
    Container<int,list<int>> c5;
}
```

Все пытаюсь себя представить компилятором.

Вижу

```
Container<int,vector<int>> c1;
```

Ага, значит, в определении

```
template<typename T = double, typename C = vector<T>>
requires (t_IsVectorOrArray<T,C>::value)
struct Container
```

мы УЖЕ имеем `T == int` и С == `vector<int>`. Нам не нужно их выводить, они указаны явно.

Теперь нужно выбрать один из трех классов

```
class t_IsVectorOrArray<int,vector<int>>

class t_IsVectorOrArray<int,::std::array<int, count>>

class t_IsVectorOrArray<int,::std::vector<int, vector<int>>>
```

Если я компилятор, то я сразу выбрасываю `array` - там нужен какой-то `count`, которого у меня нет. Остаются

```
class t_IsVectorOrArray<int,vector<int>>
class t_IsVectorOrArray<int,::std::vector<int, vector<int>>>
```

Но второе определение - какой-то бред, его тоже надо выбросить. Остается первое, false.

Что в моих рассуждениях не так?

Если считать, что типы для `t_IsVectorOrArray<T,C>` еще не выведены - то нам их и вывести не из чего.

С `array` - nen хоть как-то понятно... есть лишний параметр шаблона, который мы не знаем, но его хотя бы можем вывести из определения, например, из

```
    Container<int,array<int,4>> c4;
```

получаем

```
class t_IsVectorOrArray<int,array<int, 4>>
class t_IsVectorOrArray<int,array<int, count>>
class t_IsVectorOrArray<int,vector<int,array<int, 4>>>
```

Опять последний бред выбрасываем, во втором можем вывести `count == 4` и тогда под определение проходит

```
class t_IsVectorOrArray<int,array<int,4>>
```

при этом параметр фактически самый простой, просто `int` и просто 4, в то время как для первого случая второй параметр
`array<int,4>`, так что выбирается второй случай.

Но кажется мне, что я и тут не так рассуждаю.

А как надо?

Comment: А точно нужен именно вектор или массив? Не любой непрерывный контейнер?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Да я и с этими уже замахался — у них же размеры по-разному определяются. А если еще вообще какой-то массив из С... Вы намекаете на Random Access iterator? Наличие операции индексирования?

Comment: Да вроле одинаково, `.size()`. А если написать `std::size(x)`, то можно и сырые массивы поддержать. Аналогично `std::data(x)` - если они оба есть, то это непрерывный контейнер. Последний использовать для доступа к элементам, или `a[b]`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Я имел в виду создание. Конструктор массива должен быть известен во время компиляции, и сам размер массива меняться не должен. Вектов - наоборот. И как мне, скажем, член обобщенно инициализировать? Сложновато. А если еще какой-то заранее неизвестный контейнер будет, то еще страшнее. Или есть какой-то способ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вроде тривиальный трейт.

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <cstddef>

template<typename T>
class t_IsVectorOrArray
{
    public: static constexpr bool value{false};
};

template<typename Item, ::std::size_t count>
class t_IsVectorOrArray<::std::array<Item, count>>
{
    public: static constexpr bool value{true};
};

template<typename... Args>
class t_IsVectorOrArray<::std::vector<Args...>>
{
    public: static constexpr bool value{true};
};

#include <list>
static_assert(not t_IsVectorOrArray<int>::value);
static_assert(not t_IsVectorOrArray<::std::list<int>>::value);
static_assert(t_IsVectorOrArray<::std::array<int, 4>>::value);
static_assert(t_IsVectorOrArray<::std::vector<int>>::value);
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCBmABykAA6oCoRODB7evnrJqY4CQSHhLFEx8baY9vkMQgRMxASZPn5cFVXptfUEhWGR0XoKdQ1N2a2DXT3FpRIAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMzByN5YANQma271xEwAnvvYJhoAguub25h7BwBumA4k55c3ZhsMW167%2BzcyEG6CwVA%2B10%2BBEwLESBmhgIIJ0SjFYDwAKhCrlsmAoFDsCAB9ACSCgAaq8iMQAPLEK7EY5nSEAdis1x2HJ2iS8EVoeGQIB240cyB2aAYg0wqkSxB2EVQnh2TzEXkwJlZVDESnVABF9mybsy9WsDVCYXCmAiDkiUcw2DtidCWKQdiAQCC3akAF6YQkEMULQRYnF4gkk8mUki0%2BmMwGegjoN1HU6Ax0wl1oLxBtYXHOfdUGzlcnl8gVCuoigMS6HS2XyxXK7xq1kEYiq3X6/NGzuQ65Oi1Wtw21FsAB04529OACmDBlDRNJFLeNLpDJTB3jiZAL2XgKnCnHo4%2BeZZhc53N5/MFwv5VcltblCtoSpVzYsrfb3ZNXeNpsh3zuf4HkBPlBixG9kEJXElAaCAGFQf0FwjZdozXM4DmCAhzjdRtVRmHsrggqC8WiAg4IQsNF0jFcY3XNxNzdUCsIw7Nc2wHDX3w79riI6DSIgJClypVDYw3d0EyTNDAUwl1JGPdjt04gjeJI2DBOokS6IY7dqOk1jsMUpsuINDg5loTgAFZeD8DgtFIVBODcaxrCFBYlmA74eFIAhNFMuYAGsQAsjR9E4SRrN8%2BzOF4BQQBCnzbNM0g4FgGBEBQVBYToaJyEoNAsvoGJgC4NZWiwJ5%2BUwMk8EwAB3albU4LyaFoaFiFiiAIkiiJgnqE4mt4HrmGIE5qQibRKQG0h8rYQRqQYWh%2BsS0gsAiLxgEOWhaFi7heCwFhDGAcRlvwYhKTwF4drsqVXi8aEpswypIr5CJjhGjwsEi1s8BYAa5ioAxp2quqGsYKb%2BEEEQxHYKQZEERQVHUZbdFaAwjBQZzLH0PAIliyA5lQRJqh2gBaEmQX2HVTEsawzA0HYSYAdTEZ8malVsmAZxmUXQQwRV4VAXgZPAsDxiA5jsc7nAgVwRhaUhAmCXoSn6VpcjSAQ5ZyFINYYSY%2BhiMZKilmohkaTxmgGY2HA6M39ZVw3bDNrWxjtpWplViW3OWWZQo4KzSBsuyHI4HZVDiAA2EmI8kHZgGQUUStHLgdggXBCBIPZPJmXgEq0GYAqCkLzI4cLSF%2B4LA8ikOYri7zfLmFL0oWAhuQIXKIHyxJsuIUI0U4cOo5juOE52JOvMwfAqRFvQIeEURxFhueEbUSKUdIWrjkSP6/YDoOBc4ak7rbnZUCoMPI%2Bj2P48TtZk9TjwCuiLPSpz%2BvEoL0gEEwJgsBicW/ZlwriFfeUUOC13ig3QulcS5rAistGu7985mU4GYeBwdopIL8qQIWqRnCSCAA%3D%3D)

Вариант с заданием хранимого типа:

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <cstddef>

template<typename X, typename T>
class t_IsVectorOrArray
{
    public: static constexpr bool value{false};
};

template<typename X, ::std::size_t count>
class t_IsVectorOrArray<X, ::std::array<X, count>>
{
    public: static constexpr bool value{true};
};

template<typename X, typename... Args>
class t_IsVectorOrArray<X, ::std::vector<X, Args...>>
{
    public: static constexpr bool value{true};
};

#include <list>
static_assert(not t_IsVectorOrArray<int, int>::value);
static_assert(not t_IsVectorOrArray<int, ::std::list<int>>::value);
static_assert(not t_IsVectorOrArray<int, ::std::array<float, 4>>::value);
static_assert(not t_IsVectorOrArray<int, ::std::vector<float>>::value);
static_assert(t_IsVectorOrArray<int, ::std::array<int, 4>>::value);
static_assert(t_IsVectorOrArray<int, ::std::vector<int>>::value);
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCAAzBqkAA6oCoRODB7evnrJqY4CQSHhLFEx8baY9vkMQgRMxASZPn5cFVXptfUEhWGR0XoKdQ1N2a2DXT3FpRIAlLaoXsTI7BzmscHI3lgA1CaxbvXETACee9gmGgCCaxtbmLv7AG6YDiRnF9dm6wybXjt7bmQg3QWCo7yuHwImBYiQMUIBBGOiUYrHuAA1SNtEcjmGxtgAVcGXTZMBQKLEAfQAkgoAGovIjEADyxEuxCOpwhAHYrFdtvztokvBFaHhkCBtuNHMhtmgGINMKpEsRthFUJ5to8xF5MCYeVQxEo9QARPa865c02xc2Q6Gwpjw/bYlF4jHbEAgYEe1IAL0wFIIsoWgiJJLJlJp9NezNZ7JOALd3oI6A9h3j%2BzdaC8Idi51zHz15oFguFovFkrq0qD8qhSpVao1Wu8up5BGIOpNZoLlq7EKuUJhcN1TqRLvRmOduMwADpZ9s2cAFKGDOGCNS6QySCy2RyE5ikymQM9o3v58RF7Pp%2B989yiwKhSKxRKpWLqwq66r1bRNdqWxY2x2PbWt2Vo2hCXy3H89wAqKgxEi%2ByAUqSSgNBADCoIGa6RpuMY7umbjBAQmKEWcHpNjqMy9pcCFIWS0QEGhGERhu0bbnGpz7IR%2B6esmHqwQQAIkfmuZkb%2BlHAVcNHIfRjGYeuUaMmxu6cYI3FeiAaYcW4VC0KgDqYpI17YKJzbieaUl0ah6FydhrGxspBGqe6PGHsejIAjpekCcJxlHmJVEWShDFYSxin2fhXHOepmmCU5hk%2BSZFEBZWYq0UFEAhQpW7hVpkUHmROGxd5ea%2BeRmBmR8HBzLQnAAKy8H4HBaKQqCcG41jWJKCxLNBXw8KQBCaFVcwANYgLVCQ1RwkgNUNLWcLwCggAkg1NVVpBwLAMCICgqAwnQ0TkJQaD7fQMTAFwsStFgjxipgtJ4JgADuTI4pw/U0LQULEEtEARHNETBPUxzvbwgPMMQxxMhE2gMqDpAnWwghMgwtAg2tpBYBEXjAActC0Et3C8FgLCGMA4gY/gxAMngzyE81iovF4ULw4RlRzaKERHJDHhYHNbZ4CwoNzDpTCLg9z2vYw8P8IIIhiOwUgyIIigqOoGO6K0BhGCgHWWPoeAREtkBzKgiTVITAC0lvAnsxqmJY1hmBo2yWwA6mI37u4qbZMK7bvIughjSrwqDPOyeBYMbEBzHYNPOBArgjC0pCBMEvQlP0rS5GkAjJzkKS5wwkx9DEYyVPHNRDI0njNAMFcOB01cl5nZe2NX%2BdjM36dTFnsfdcssz6HVs0Y61HDbKoAAcABslsz5I2zAMgMqXdOXDbBAuCECQux9TMvCrVoMyjeNk2cDNpBCxNpCNc14%2BLctA1DXMm07QsBBCkRFAQCdiQHcQUIqJODTzngvJeK9thr36pgfAjJI56FlsIUQ4glZINVmoOamtSBPSOIkYWw8OD1VvnNceTJmZf22KgKgk9Z7z0XsvVesR16bw8KdaIe8roH2fmtE%2BpAECYCYFgGIMdCGX2vgkO%2BocFq2CfkfYapAxo3ymrEUe98ZHyL4VNMwajpEcEPi/OY4dUjOEkEAA%3D%3D)

Comment: Спасибо, я что-то зациклился на использовании стандартных `is_*`. Но теперь я еще вижу, что мне надо проверить, чтоб вектор или массив были определенного тпа, что-то вроде `template<typename T = double, typename C = vector<T>> struct Container`, вобщем, контейнеры указанного типа. Я пока написал `template<typename T = double, typename C = vector<T>>
requires (t_IsVectorOrArray<C>::value && is_same_v<typename C::value_type,T>)
struct Container`, и это работает, но не соображу пока, а как добавить эту проверку прямо в ваш `t_IsVectorOrArray`? Не покажете?

Comment: Первым параметром для `array` и `vector` поставьте нужный тип вместо шаблонного.

Comment: Посмотрите "Добавление для user7860670" в вопросе. Вы это имели в виду?

Comment: Нет конечно. Я же ничего не писал про добавление параметров в `t_IsVectorOrArray`. Достаточно написать `::std::array<double, count>`

Comment: Если вы имели в виду конкретный тип, то я же не знаю, каким он будет. Надо совпадение типа T и типа элемента в векторе/массиве.

Comment: А, ну тогда `t_IsVectorOrArray<T,::std::array<T, count>>` `<T,::std::vector<T, Args...>>`

Comment: И те самые мои `is_same`? Для `array`?

Comment: `is_same` не нужны.

Comment: И я чего-то не понимаю. Как, например, в `t_IsVectorOrArray<int,vector<double>>` происходит вывод? `Args` в `t_IsVectorOrArray` получается `vector<double>`, и что дальше за `vector<int,vector<int,vector<double>>`? Какие-то чудеса...

Comment: Если не нужен, то как написать для `array`? `template<typename T, typename Item, ::std::size_t count>class t_IsVectorOrArray<T,::std::array<T, count>>`? так же не работает? Если `template<typename T, typename Item, ::std::size_t count>
class t_IsVectorOrArray<T,::std::array<Item, count>>`, то нет проверки на равенство T и Item.

Comment: Не могли бы вы дать развернутый ответ с кодом и пояснениями, как это работает? Я потом через конкурс добавлю плюсиков )) (Пока для этого снял галоочку принятия, чтоб конкурс можно было объявить).

Comment: Если написать `t_IsVectorOrArray<int,vector<double>>`, то `t_IsVectorOrArray<T,::std::vector<T, Args...>>` действительно не работает и будет выбран общая реализация, вот и все. Если не понятно, как работает выбор шаблонных специализаций, то лучше задать новый вопрос. Хотя ответ на самом деле потянет не небольшую книгу.

Comment: А для `array`? Ему же передается на один параметр больше, он вообще никогда не должен выбираться - мы же передаем только один шаблонный параметр? Ох, думал, что хоть немного понимаю, но, похоже, чем дальше, тем больше не понимаю даже того, что раньше думал, понимаю ((

Comment: А если передать `t_IsVectorOrArray<int,array<double, 4>>`, то `t_IsVectorOrArray<T,::std::array<T,  count>>` действительно не работает и будет выбрана общая реализация, вот и все.

Comment: А для `t_IsVectorOrArray<int,array<int, 4>>` почему будет выбрана нужная специалиизация? Мы же нигде в t_IsVectorOrArray отдельно четверку не передаем?

Comment: Из 4 будет выведен шаблонный параметр `count`. Собственно уточнение второго шаблонного параметра `T` как типа `::std::array<X, count>` приведет к тому, что при ранжировании частичных шаблонных специализация по степени специализации эта специализация получит приоритет по сравнению с общей реализацией.

Comment: Пошел курить какого-нибудь Вандервурда... Это все надо переварить, запутался вконец... (( Понял только, что на кривой Даннинга-Крюгера я свалился в яму ))

Comment: Уже голова болит от книжек... Чем дальше, тем больше не понимаю эти специализации. Изложил во втором дополнении к вопросу свое неверное понимание. А как верно? Если я - компилятор, как я должен рассуждать? не дайте помереть дураком... И еще - это какое-то отношение к SFINAE имеет или нет?

Comment: Мне кажется, что тут явно стоит задать новый вопрос, потому что в исходный вопрос про трейт вектор или массив оно уже никак не укладывается... Ну и к SFINAE это отношения не имеет.

Answer (score 1):

Вы не с той стороны подходите.

Давайте попробуем так: у вас есть `Container<int,array<int,4>> c4;`

И три объявления

```
template<typename X, typename T>
class t_IsVectorOrArray

template<typename X, ::std::size_t count>
class t_IsVectorOrArray<X, ::std::array<X, count>>

template<typename X, typename... Args>
class t_IsVectorOrArray<X, ::std::vector<X, Args...>>
```

Просто сравните (не смотря на часть `template`), на что это похоже больше всего? Правда, на `class t_IsVectorOrArray<X, ::std::array<X, count>>`, где `X` — это `int`, а `count` — 4? Прям тютелька в тютельку.

На `class t_IsVectorOrArray<X, ::std::vector<X, Args...>>` это в принципе не похоже, нет тут никакого массива.

И на `class t_IsVectorOrArray` - да, годится... но уже не совсем в ту самую тютельку, потому что второй параметр получается слишком сложным. Так что выбираем эту самую тютельку.

Точно так же, если возьмем вектор — тоже сработает, но уже на векторе. Еще раз: на часть `template` не реагируем. Что оно там выберет — это его проблемы. Главное, что мы имеем конкретные типы, подходящие под наши объявления.

Если же написать что-то не годящееся ни для вектора, ни для массива, или не совпадающее по типам элементов и типу из первого параметра — вариантов нет, работает *только* первый вариант, с `false`.

Так понятнее?

Отталкивайтесь не от первой строки с `template`, а от второй, с видом класса.

Comment: Кажется, дошло... Спасибо!